# How do I remove all the zero's from a dataset that is in a list?

Tags: python, list, dataset, libsvm, zero

I have this dataset in an excel spreadsheet and I have converted into a csv file for python to read:

```
1   5   0   1   3   2   1   18  30  50  13  12  24  1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10  10  12  10  6   16  -1
0   7   0   0   4   4   1   21  30  46  19  11  25  1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   2   4   3   4   2   5   -1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   4   4   7   3   6   6   -1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   4   -1
2   1   0   0   1   1   1   8   7   12  5   5   12  -1
2   5   0   0   2   2   1   24  20  45  14  12  28  -1
2   5   0   0   3   3   1   14  17  21  9   12  18  -1
0   5   0   0   2   2   1   17  12  25  8   13  19  1
23  25  0   22  13  12  11  112 125 240 39  27  165 1
```

From this I need an output file in python format which prints in lists without the 0's. In other words, each row or column should not have any zero's. Please look below at the example format that should be printed.

```
+1 1:0.708333 2:1 3:1 4:-0.320755 5:-0.105023 6:-1 7:1 8:-0.419847 9:-1 10:-0.225806 12:1 13:-1 
-1 1:0.583333 2:-1 3:0.333333 4:-0.603774 5:1 6:-1 7:1 8:0.358779 9:-1 10:-0.483871 12:-1 13:1
+1 1:0.166667 2:1 3:-0.333333 4:-0.433962 5:-0.383562 6:-1 7:-1 8:0.0687023 9:-1 10:-0.903226 11:-1 12:-1 13:1
-1 1:0.458333 2:1 3:1 4:-0.358491 5:-0.374429 6:-1 7:-1 8:-0.480916 9:1 10:-0.935484 12:-0.333333 13:1
-1 1:0.875 2:-1 3:-0.333333 4:-0.509434 5:-0.347032 6:-1 7:1 8:-0.236641 9:1 10:-0.935484 11:-1 12:-0.333333 13:-1
-1 1:0.5 2:1 3:1 4:-0.509434 5:-0.767123 6:-1 7:-1 8:0.0534351 9:-1 10:-0.870968 11:-1 12:-1 13:1
+1 1:0.125 2:1 3:0.333333 4:-0.320755 5:-0.406393 6:1 7:1 8:0.0839695 9:1 10:-0.806452 12:-0.333333 13:0.5
+1 1:0.25 2:1 3:1 4:-0.698113 5:-0.484018 6:-1 7:1 8:0.0839695 9:1 10:-0.612903 12:-0.333333 13:1
+1 1:0.291667 2:1 3:1 4:-0.132075 5:-0.237443 6:-1 7:1 8:0.51145 9:-1 10:-0.612903 12:0.333333 13:1
```

EDIT:

import csv
list_new = []

with open('testingSeta.csv') as csvfile:

```
 for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
     row.insert(0, row.pop())
     list_new.append(row)

 list_new.pop(0)
```

print list_new

There are no zeros on their own. This is what I have so far. Please help. Thank You

Comment: How do you get from your input to your output? They look completely unrelated to me.

Comment: What type of output is that? just a pure raw string? a 2d list?

Comment: there is an input module for python called csv "import csv" which enables python to read a spreadsheet. This is my code atm:

import csv
list_new = []

with open('testingSeta.csv') as csvfile:
        for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
            row.insert(0, row.pop())
            list_new.append(row)

        list_new.pop(0)

print list_new

Comment: Stretching my imagination I think what happens is that the 'input' is actually how the data looks when opening the csv file in excel (as i can't see any commas) and when the actual data is imported to python it shows that the numbers are float not integers?

Comment: how do i copy my python code in here properly?

Comment: to answer your question, the example one used floats but the one i am doing are integers. not sure if that matters.

Comment: I have included my code so far, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what row.insert(0, row.pop()) is actually moving the last element of the list to be the first and shifting the rest of the list to the right.
Also list_new.pop(0) is removing the element you have just inserted.
I suggest you to put some print statements to see what your code is doing at each step:

```
import csv
list_new = []
with open('testingSeta.csv') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        print row
        row.insert(0, row.pop())
        print row
        list_new.append(row)
        print list_new
        list_new.pop(0)
        print list_new
print list_new
```

to remove the occurrences of '0' in the list row you can do this:

```
import csv
list_new = []
with open('testingSeta.csv') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        print row
        while '0' in row: row.remove('0')
        print row
        list_new.append(row)
        print list_new
for row in list_new: print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what I wanted to know plain and simple is how to remove the zeros from a list within a list. Thanks

Comment: I've edited the answer with a possible solution to your problem

Comment: The solution worked perfectly. Thanks, much appreciated. Can you help to separate a list within a list so that it shows each list row by row?

Comment: This is what is printing when I run the program.

[['1', '1', '5', '1', '3', '2', '1', '18', '30', '50', '13', '12', '24'], ['-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '10', '10', '12', '10', '6', '16'], ['1', '7', '4', '4', '1', '21', '30', '46', '19', '11', '25'], ['-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '4', '3', '4', '2', '5'], ['-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '4', '4', '7', '3', '6', '6'], ['-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4'], ['-1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '8', '7', '12', '5', '5', '12']

Comment: I've edited the code to print one row at a time using.

Comment: When I run the code to open the data in a new excel spreadsheet, the headers still appear but they do not appear in the python program when I run it. I cannot seem to find the right code for it.

Comment: How can I print so that there is no comma between each value. Can you help me please?

Comment: print ' '.join(row) should do it, but please don't post more questions as comments. Search SO for the answer first and if you don't find it then post it as a new question, which will help other people looking for an  answer to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing what you want to do

- if you want to have the second file format (scaled libsvm input) without zeroes - while svm-scale does not print zero values it is safe to do that. the only disadvantage is a larger file.
- if you really do remove the zeroes from the scaled libsvm input take care to keep the feature numbers i. e. `1 1:0.5 2:0 3:-0.5` shall result in `1 1:0.5 3:-0.5`
- if you want to remove the zeroes from the first file format (unscaled feature vectors) - this is just plain wrong as the scaled value may be different from zero.